# Phaser.io 3: Get game size in scene

Tags: phaser-framework

It seems to be a simple question, but I just cannot resolve it:

I'm using Phaser.io 3 HTML5 game framework with ES6 classes, and I try to figure out the actual "Game Size" (or canvas / viewport size), so that I can center an object on screen:

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('ship', 'assets/spaceship3.png');
    }

    create() {

        let ship = this.add.sprite(160,125, 'ship');
        // Here I need to figure out the screen width / height:
        // ---> How do I achieve that?
        ship.setPosition(width / 2, height / 2);
    }
}
```

I could not find a way to either read or calculate the actual viewport's / canvas' size. Any hints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the default camera:

```js
ship.setPosition(this.cameras.main.centerX, this.cameras.main.centerY);
```

From [the Phaser 3 API Documentation on `Camera`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.Camera.html):

> Cameras, by default, are created the same size as your game, but their position and size can be set to anything.

Comment: Will an image placed on `this.cameras.main.centerX` and `Y` move with camera? What if I want it to be static and not to move with camera, instead being a background of the scene?

Comment: @VELFR it depends upon your logic. If you put the above in your `update()` then the image position will be updated every frame, but if you put it in `create()` then it will take the current camera's values and not move the image.

Answer (score 19):

In a scene, in the `preload()` and `create()` methods (*not* in the constructor) you can access the canvas element with `this.sys.game.canvas`. So to get the canvas size, you can do:

```js
create() {
    let { width, height } = this.sys.game.canvas;
}
```

For my part I like to add the following code to ease the access to the canvas:

```js
preload() {
    this.canvas = this.sys.game.canvas;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this only works if the canvas engine is used - when webGL is used, this does not seem to be working?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it, it's working for me in both cases

Comment: The canvas width is not the same as the game width when working with a higher DPI pixel ratio

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
scene.sys.game.scale.gameSize
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in my preload to get both the width and height.

```
    this.gameWidth = this.sys.game.canvas.width
    this.gameHeight = this.sys.game.canvas.height
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply use `game.config.width`.